# How to change bootstrap primary color to linear-gradient?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, background-color

I am trying to change bootstrap primary color to `linear-gredient` but I am getting an error:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": linear-gradient(to right, #373b44, #4286f4)
);
```

error:

> ```
> $link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
>                            ^
>       Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
> ```

Comment: What is `$link-color` ? It look like it's not a color. Can we have more of the code with the variable `$link-color` ?

Comment: $theme-colors: (
  "primary": linear-gradient(to right, #373b44, #4286f4)
); 
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; actually all code is that. There is no another code. if i put single hex color it works

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where the `$link-color` is defined :/

Comment: I am getting that error only for linear-gredient. Single hex color works. I think $link-color is a helper inside bootstrap

Comment: If I'm correct `$theme-colors` outputs the `::root { }` CSS variables structure, those variables (like `--primary` cannot accept CSS declarations (like linear gradient); only values (like unit measurements or HEX values), as they are applied via `var(--variableName)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `linear-gradient` is used for `background-image`, not foreground `color`. When the SASS compiler attempts to build Bootstrap it can't use the darken(..) function on a background-image.

Instead you can just change the `primary` color for the elements that have a background like this...

```
.bg-primary,
.btn-primary,
.badge-primary,
.alert-primary {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #373b44, #4286f4);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/XXUxFr6tEZ

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Gradient background?
`$primary-color` is primarily used for setting `color` style rule, not background. Also it's used for computing other colors depending on it, `$link-color` for example.
In your case sass parser is trying to make link look darker on hover, trying to apply darken function to linear gradient.
If you are trying to make linear-gradient background - you need to set variable that handles background-image. For gradient text you need to read about `background-clip`

[Gradient Text](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/)

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- set `$enable-gradients: true`
- override `.bg-gradient-primary` class with your gradient as background
- add `.bg-gradient-primary` class to your element

example:

```
<button class="btn bg-gradient-primary border-0">Connect Wallet</button>
```

[image]